# Access Images and videos from android internal Storage using Unity C#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

i am trying to access the **Whatsapp**  folder from android internal storage but for some reason this code is not working the file path is correct but this if statement never gets true

here is the code for checking if file exixts

```
public static Texture2D LoadPNG()
{

    Texture2D tex = null;
    byte[] fileData;

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        Debug.Log("file exists");
        fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        tex.LoadImage(fileData); //..this will auto-resize the texture dimensions.
    }
    return tex;
}
```

now **filepath = "/storage/emulated/0/Whatsapp/Media/.statuses**

code which makes this path

```
public static string GetDownloadFolder()
{
    string[] temp = (Application.persistentDataPath.Replace("Android", "")).Split(new string[] { "//" }, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
    filePath = temp[0]+"/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses";
    return (temp[0] + "/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses");

}
```

now problem is that in android device this .statuses folder have images and video files but this if statement never gets called why i dont understand even path is correct

```
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    Debug.Log("file exists");
    fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
    tex.LoadImage(fileData); //..this will auto-resize the texture dimensions.
}
```

Comment: did you add permission for your app?

Comment: yes in player setting in write permission i set it to external

Comment: Yes same issue.How do you set permission?

Comment: The above script using File.Exits works for MAC/WINDOWS but not for android.

Comment: then how to do it with android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you check if file exists at folder path. 
The solution is check if path is directory and get all files from it:

```
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        string filenames[] = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        foreach (var filename in filenames)
        {
            LoadPNG(filename);
        }
    }
```

Comment: let me implement this

Comment: this is giving me errors on array declaration and on LoadPNG(filename) method

Comment: How did u solve it?I managed to solve it using it IEnumerator